# How do you combine multiple images in React Native?

Tags: android, ios, react-native

I'm not sure this is the best place for this, but I can't seem to find what I need. I'm new to React Native and I'm looking for a module that will allow me to combine multiple images together.

I've searched everywhere and can't seem to find one. Aside from rolling my own I'd figured I would ask if someone knows of one first.

Thanks!

Edit: Revising this with more details. So I was writing an app that was going to take an image from and overlay it on the camera. Then when you snap the photo to combine the images and save to your phone. I guess you can say similar to a Snapchat filter.

The first answer with the bit about the canvas way was something I had an idea of doing, but the app essentially died. But it would still be good info to know if there was another module out there for this kind of task.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please [take the tour]( https://stackoverflow.com/tour), make sure you read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and updated your question with more information.

Answer (score 0):

now I'm using react-native-view-shot.
make wrapper view and locate two image component.
and just shot.

///
I've got the same problem, and there are no modules available, but there are two ways to do this.

1. you can develop your own native module.
   I'm using this method. I think this is the best way for combine multiple images. could be fast, small, and All parts are under your control.
   but it have some issues for this.
   you should use android and ios develop language. difficult to optimize and  if you don't have any chances for study those languages, it will be challenge or shit. 
   I'm using this method but I can't make it for IOS now..
2. Use react webview canvas module.
   actually , I'm consider to use this method.
   there are many react native canvas modules and you can use It same as canvas on web.
   so send your images to one canvas and combine then get DataURL and convert to image file.
   It may seems inefficient. but easy and It will move as you intended.

Best answer is... someone publish imagecombine module and just use it.

Answer (score -1):

Do you just mean displaying multiple images in a single view? You can do it fairly simply without a module.

```
<View>
    <Image />
    <Image />
    <Image />
</View>
```